# About virtual functions, why are printed values of *(int*)&b and (int*)*(int*)&b different?

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions

The type is changed but I think `*(int*)&b` and `(int*)*(int*)&b` should be pointing to the same address.

Here's the source file. It'd be grateful if you can help me about why the two outputs of line A is different.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>    
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
typedef void (*fun)();
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f(){cout<<'f'<<endl;}
    virtual void g(){cout<<'g'<<endl;}
    virtual void h(){cout<<'h'<<endl;}
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base b;
    cout<<*(int*)&b<<endl<<(int*)*(int*)&b<<endl; //A
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer for a more detailed explanation regarding the different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your question has no connection to virtual functions whatsoever. As far as the different output goes, the reason is the following:

1. Expression `*(int*)&b` takes the address of object `b`, casts it into a pointer to an integer, and then dereferences it, thus producing an integer value.
2. Expression `(int*)*(int*)&b` does all of the steps of above, but it then takes that integer value and casts it into an integer pointer. Although it has the same numerical value, it now a pointer type, which causes it to be displayed in hexadecimal form when it is printed using `<<` operator, whereas an integer value will be displayed in decimal form. This is the reason that you are seeing different output.

Note that you should not be converting on object of some class in order to print it. If you want to print an object using `<<`, you need to overload that operator. Please take a look at **operator overloading**:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: I got it. I just wanted to get the address of the first virtual function... Anyway I think you've given me a perfect answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PandaLee You are welcome! If you think the answer was good, consider marking it as accepted as a token of appreciation for my time and effort. Best of luck in learning more of C++.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that your code is undefined, the difference is that one expression is a pointer and the other isn't.

Replace `Base b;` with `int b;` to make it clearer (and well defined).

Then `*(int*)&b` is equivalent to `*&b`, which is `b`, an `int`.
On the other hand, `(int*)*(int*)&b` is equivalent to `(int*)*&b`, which is `(int*)b`, an `int*`.

Comment: However I can't cout<<b; on VS2010, but I can cout<<*(int *)&b. So it makes a difference. Thank you very much for answering my 1st question here and it'd be so kind of you if you can explain this.

Comment: @PandaLee You could `cout << b;` if you defined a suitable overload of `operator<<`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot, once again.